# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError Element does not exist in cache

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

## It's not my actual code but the scenario is exactly the same.

## mysite.com is something like this:

```
<iframe name:something1>
    <form id:something2> 
        <ul>
        <li>
            <input class = "class a" id = "id1" name = "name1">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input class = "class b" id = "id2" name = "name2">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input class = "class c" id = "id3" name = "name3">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id = "sbmt_btn" type = "submit">
        </li>

        </ul>
    </form>
</iframe>
```

## Watir script I used:

```
require "watir-webdriver"
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b.goto "mysite.com"
b.frame(:name, "something1").text_field(:id, "id1").set "45"     #line1
b.frame(:name, "something1").text_field(:id, "id2").set "Hello"  #line2
b.frame(:name, "something1").text_field(:id, "id3").set "World"  #line3
b.frame(:name, "something1").button(:id, "sbmt_btn").click       #line4
```

**Problem:** line1 and line2 runs successfully. But system throws error while executing line3. System couldn't find objects with id= id3 and id = sbmt_btn. I went through many pages to solve this but couldn't. Help please.
My ruby version: ruby 1.9.3p362

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the page changing (via ajax or javascript) as you input each field?

Comment: +1 for what Justin just asked.  Search the page HTML and JS code to see if there are postback events being triggered by onchange events or something of that sort.

Comment: They are all in the same form. And there are no such events triggered while changing the input fields. I went through your website too Justin Ko but couldn't find the solution for me.

Comment: I ran your sample script against the sample page and did not get any exception. Do you get the exception with your sample page/script? If not, there must be something different about the actual page you are testing. You need to provide more information so that we can reproduce the problem - the actual page or a sample page that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. The problem has been solved. When I went through the code with the help of form developer, I found that there were no events but the field was built along with a plugin. That was creating the problem. :)

Comment: @Dovinsth It would be very helpful to other users who might have the same or similar issues if you would  1) edit your question, include the name of the plugin or library that was being used, maybe even alter the title to include it.  2) Add an answer to the question that describes what you did to fix the problem, and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the when_present command:

```
. . .
b.frame(:name, "something1").text_field(:id, "id3").when_present.set "World"
. . .
```